# Customized activity indicator with text message

Tags: objective-c, ios8.1, activity-indicator

I know this question has been asked many times before and there are many libraries on `github`. But I don't find any fulfilling requirements. In my previous apps, I was using `MBProgressHUD`. No doubt, its a great and simple library. But for my current app, client requires activity indicator like image below. I tried out some libraries like TYMActivityIndicatorView. But this doesn't text under rotating indicator. Please suggest me any library so that I could get this like `indicatorView`. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why will `MBProgressHUD` not be appropriate for this?

Comment: you can use MBProgressHud for showing text under label

Comment: Actually I don't know if I can  make this like activity indicator with MBProgressHUD ?

Comment: @Misha, Yes i know. But can I change that rotating indicator in MBProgressHUD ?

Comment: try using MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate

Comment: @Misha  `MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate` doesn't work. I tried `MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate`, but it also doesn't seem to work. I want activity indicator to rotate until the processing completes.

Comment: Why cant you create a view and add the activity indicator and the Label in it as per your layout, and show or hide this view based on you need? That way you have complete control over it.

Comment: Well, I can create it. But how to get activity indicator like that in above image. Default iOS activity indicator is quite different from this.